# SSRS (inconsistently) replaces special characters with HTML entity codes

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, special-characters, html-entities

Our UI has a few fields which are free-text boxes, generally for the user to added descriptions and comments about an item that other form elements do not cover.  The users have entered a variety of things, sometimes including characters, and so far the MSSQL 2008 r2 database has handled it well.

Now, we have added SSRS reports to the application, and *some* users are finding when the report runs, that special characters are being replaced, by what the users call "garbledygook" by which I can identify as HTML entity codes.  A couple specific examples:

As in the UI/DB: "... we need to have R&D evaluate ..."

On the report: "... we need to have R`&amp;`D evaluate ..."

As in the UI/DB: "I suggest "rapid" utilization of ..."

On the report: "I suggest `&quot;`rapid`&quot;` utilization of of ..."

As in the UI/DB: "Updating the savings values.(carriage return)Also revised ..."

On the report: "Updating the savings values.`&#x0D;`Also revised ..."

The trouble is with the emphasis on *some* users.  Preliminary indications are that IE8 is among the offenders, but not all IE8 users have seen this, and none of us DEVs can replicate it in any of our environments.

So two questions really, what is the cause?  And, what is the solution?

Comment: Are the users doing copy/paste from another application like Internet Explorer or Word?

Comment: Actually I should say first you should check if the HTML entities are actually stored in the SQL table, which is likely the case. In that event this isn't really an SSRS question.

Comment: @JC that was the first thing I checked.  These characters are in the DB as I show in the question.  They are only changed to entity codes in SSRS report outputs.

Comment: Are you able to have users swap workstations and see if the issue follows them or is associated with their PC? Do you have multiple users looking at the exact same report run and some seeing entity codes where others do not? Not to belabor the question, but have you verified the database data by examining it directly through SQL Management Studio rather than just seeing it through the application UI?

Comment: @JC: The "As in the UI/DB" versions I give above, I really mean both UI and DB.  These come from `select comment from <<table>> where id=<<value>>` type queries, and from viewing the item via the application in a web browser.

Comment: Okay. So the exact same data with html entity codes displays correctly in SSRS on some workstations and not others. You mentioned some correlation with IE8 but not all IE8 users see it. Are all the users who do see it using IE8?

Comment: Just a couple of other ideas for finding the common thread: Could some of the IE8 users be using compatibility mode and others not? If you have multiple SSRS servers load balanced, could all of the bad formatting be coming from the same server?

Comment: @JC:  You've about got it.  There's just one SSRS server.  I was finally able to find a place where I can replicate myself: My own BIDS preview mode had it for line breaks.  I will try to ask the users about compatibility mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could HTML decode it in the report. On the report properties references tab you have to add the assembly `System.Web`. Then you can use the expression:

```
=System.Web.HttpUtility.HTMLDecode(Fields!MyField.Value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Bit of an old question, but you can set any given textbox to interpret HTML as styling by modifying the placeholder settings as here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207057.aspx

This includes `&#174;` character codes, `<b></b>` and `<i></i>` for some basics to work with.